# What is this IE CSS bug called? (Double vertical padding)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

*(Note, this is not the double-margin bug. I'm calling this the double-vertical-padding bug for now unless someone else has a more clever/documented name for this?)*

Just when I thought I'd seen all the quirky IE CSS bugs, I've produced a simple test case that continues to confuse me. The page below looks and works great in FF, Opera, et al. However, IE 6 and IE 7 seem to be confused.  I will let the document I'm pasting below speak for itself.

**Edit:** I've put this at the following URL:  http://jsbin.com/efele 
Open it up in IE and again in FF. Compare.

My question is: what is this bug called? (Have I missed this somewhere? Is it found on [this page](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html)?) I'm familiar with the 3px jog bug and the double-(horizontal)-margin bug and lots of other float-related bugs. But... vertical padding is being duplicated? (And put in the wrong place, to boot.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>IE bork!</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#container {
 border:1px solid red;
 background-color:#CC99CC;
 width:800px;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-top:100px;
}
#sidebar {
 float:left;
 display:inline;
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid blue;
 background-color:#00CCFF;
}
#content {
 float:right;
 display:inline;
 width:510px;
 border:1px solid green;
 background-color:#66CC99;
}
.clear {
 clear:both;
 /* height:0px; <<< setting height seems to be the only thing that makes this work as expected?!? */
 background-color:#CCCCCC; /* bg color here is just for debugging */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">I am the sidebar</div>
    <div id="content">I am the content</div>
    <div class="clear"><!-- clear! --></div>
</div>
<p>There should be 100px of space above the two floats, but <em>no</em> space below them...</p>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S., I did eventually figure out how to appease IE on this. The solution (explicitly setting a height on my "clear" div) is commented out in order to show the bug. I only wish I could have the last few hours of my life back that it took me to stumble across the real issue/solution!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the solution you found, it seems to be the [hasLayout](http://haslayout.net/haslayout) IE quirk.  (*Explicitly setting the height on your clear div set `hasLayout` to `true` in the eyes of IE*)

Comment: I was hoping for a fun/clever name such as those at the site you linked; I suppose I'll have to settle for something boring!!

Answer (score 2):

On a side note, in cases where specifying height won't work for some reason, I've often found that including `zoom:1;` anytime I need hasLayout to trigger in IE has been a lifesaver.  Anytime I have these types of weird layout issues in IE, I always try that to see if it's a layout refresh issue first. (Then if that doesn't work, proceed to bang head against keyboard)

Comment: Thank you. I like the banging approach too!